# sw directory reference

Tags: filesystems, directory

On [**this page**](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation) I noticed a reference to the `/sw` directory. I would like more info on this directory. For example, is `/sw` a Mac only convention or is it used on other systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/sw` is used by the [**Fink project**](http://finkproject.org/faq/general). Admittedly it does not conform to the [**Filesystem Hierarchy Standard**](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).